# ParseException Unknown function termfreq in FunctionQuery

Tags: solr

What is the right syntax if my query is formulated incorrectly in the link above for Apache 3.5 SOLR and do I have to enable anything specific in solrconfig.xml and schema.xml

Using Apache SOLR 3.5 and receiving a ParseException Uknown function termfreq in FunctionQuery(tf(text,amplifiers)'

http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?fl=score,documentPageId&defType=func&q=tf%28text,amplifiers%29

I am following the syntax on other websites because I don't know how to do it for the documentation on the wiki --> http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery

Comment: I am also following the syntax on the following blog: 
 [http://yonik.wordpress.com/2011/03/10/solr-relevancy-function-queries/][3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work, the function query **tf(field, term)** that you are attempting to use is **not available in 3.5**, browse through `ValueSourceParser` if you want to double-check. You need to get **Solr 4.x nightly build** - [Solr Nightly Build](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/NightlyBuilds) from trunk & use it, but beware **Solr 4.x** is not stable & released yet, there will be a significant level of API changes compared to 3.5.

If you are interested in poking into the code, you could for instance, if you are using `Maven` modify pom.xml to get the atrifacts from Trunk and browse the source code starting from `ValueSourceParser` that should let you know if those relevance functions exist & how their implementation is.

For Ex: You will see parsers related to the term vector function queries,

```java
 // From Solr 4 `ValueSourceParser` Trunk Source Code
 addParser("tf", new ValueSourceParser() {
    @Override
    public ValueSource parse(FunctionQParser fp) throws ParseException {
      TInfo tinfo = parseTerm(fp);
      return new TFValueSource(tinfo.field, tinfo.val, tinfo.indexedField, tinfo.indexedBytes);
    }
 });
```